# Best practice to deal with Web services while using Fragments in Android

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-asynctask, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement of developing a big app. Before starting I am searching for best practices developers are using around here. In many things I found best practices like `Navigation Drawers`,`ActionBar` and `Fragments` etc. however when I came to find some best practices for web api calls I found following two methods.

1) AsyncTask (which I am using from start of my development)

2) IntentService (New for me)

My App requires heavy amount of web calls. You can consider that every action will perform a api call. After this requirement I think my old way `AsyncTask` will not perform better. That is why I am searching for some other method. I am also using `Fragments`. I want to create some simple method to perform API calls and get result in fragments. Something like `String a = abc.getData(String url)` or some other easy method. My API gives me data in `JSON`

I need advice from some experienced developers with some examples. Modern and Best way to make API calls.

Comment: It totally depends on your own requirements. You can get data from JSON whether you use Activities or Fragments. And it doesn't matter the data is how much big, Lazy Loading can help you in that case. And that Lazy Loading can help you load Images too, but in case images you should also read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: @user3294034 Actually I want to make centralize api calls in app. I mean not create `AsyncTask` etc in every fragment or activity. Some thing like a content provider inside app which fetch content from server.

Comment: make a library project which will contain all AsyncTask related operations and from your project just make calls to that library. And instead of this you can also make a separate classes to achieve this.

Comment: After Little more research I found some thing interesting. 1) Picasso Library for loading images 2) OkHttp for HTTP calls. Lets try this. ;)

Comment: After Playing with Square’s libraries I found three which suites me. I faced many problem while combining them and creating example so I published my example on github https://github.com/AnawazInc/OkHttp-Picasso-Example-Android